# Getting file-content on AppHarbor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-io, appharbor

I recently started to create a project on AppHarbor just to try it out. And I've run into a small problem. I've created small files containing jQuery-templates which I've named .tmpl-files and placed inside "~/Templates/". To get the content of one of these files I use `HttpRequest.Current.Server.MapPath(path);`, and `File.Open`, and this all just works perfectly on my local machine, however, on AppHarbor I get that the file does not exist. Is there a workaround to make this work? Do I need to mark the files in some way, or is there something I can put inside my Web.config/project-settings that can make this work?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Be sure to mark the files as `Content` (right click file in Solution Explorer, set `Build Action` to `Content`). If you don't do this, the file will not be included in the msbuild output and thus not deployed by AppHarbor.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick :). I was certain it would be set to Content by default. Is there any way I can get VS10 to recognize .tmpl-files and automatically set them to Content?

Comment: I've been wondering the same thing, I have many content files - not just for AppHarbor Deployment, but in general. VS2010 doesn't really have a setup that I know of, that marks these.  It's manual going at this point.  :/

Comment: @Adron note that you can include whole libraries (including sublibaries) by using `*` wildcards in your .proj file.